# socket.io fails to emit in express app.post callback

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, socket.io

I have an express application that opens up a socket connection with my frontend React application.

I want to emit an event to the connected socket whenever someone sends a post request to my server with json data but socket.emit doesn't fire in a.post callback. io.sockets.emit however works fine but is of no use to me in this case.

This fails:

```
io.on('connection', (socket) => {
    app.post('/event', (req, res) => {
        socket.emit('someevent', req.body);
        res.sendStatus(200);
    }
}
```

But this passes:

```
io.on('connection', (socket) => {
    app.post('/event', (req, res) => {
        io.sockets.emit('someevent', req.body);
        res.sendStatus(200);
    }
}
```

Comment: You're adding a separate post handler (with the same URL) for every socket connection.  Only one route handler can ever run.  That's not what you want to do.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[SLaks](https://stackoverflow.com/users/34397/slaks)'s comment is correct but it did not help me solve my problem.

What I ended up doing is:

1. In the post request coming to `/event` from the client, I added a hidden input field containing the ID of socket connection.
2. Then in my `/event` route handler, I did:

   ```
   app.post('/event', function(req, res) {
     io.sockets.in(req.body.socketId).emit('someevent', req.body);
     res.sendStatus(200);
   });
   ```

This works because by default each socket connection joins a room identified with its socket-id and messages can be sent to rooms using the `io` object iteself (no need to obtain a socket object from `io.on('connection', socket =>{})`